# Why does Kong need headers host whenever request?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I do not understand why Kong required to include `host = userApi.test` in `Headers` 
when `GET localhost:8000/api/v1/test` is requested.

Are there any ways not to include the `Headers` when requested?

For example, I am using Angular to request APIs through Kong, I always need to include that `host`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

https://discuss.konghq.com/t/setup-for-one-service-without-host-header/805

DO NOT INCLUDE `hosts[]` when create a route.